# Weird behavior of groupby using parquet

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, parquet, pyarrow

I have a dataframe df with df.columns=['ID','Month','Characteristic','Value'] and I want to know how many valuea there are for the subset=['ID','Month','Characteristic'] so I created first a new column df['Count']=1 and then apply

```
db=df.groupby(['ID','Month','Characteristic']['Count'].sum()
db=db.to_frame()
db=db.reset_index()
```

The weird thing is that if I upload df as parquet using:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
_table = (pq.ParquetFile(path)
            .read(use_pandas_metadata=True))
df = _table.to_pandas(strings_to_categorical=True)
```

when I compute db it gives me a memory error because it creates all possible combination: for example even if ID1 doesn't have the characteristic C1 in month M1 in db I obtain a row like:

| ID | Characteristc | Month | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | C1 | M1 | 0 |

I said that it's weird because if first I save the parquet as csv and then upload that csv it gives me the right result, so in this case no lines with zero count. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues you have comes from the use of categorical.

Because you use `strings_to_categorical=True` when loading the data, the behaviour of the group by changes to generate an entry for every possible ID/Characteristic/Month.

You can either stop using `strings_to_categorical=True`, but this will increase the memory usage of your program.

Or you can change your group by to only show "observed" values:

```
table.to_pandas(strings_to_categorical=True).groupby(['ID','Month','Characteristic'], as_index=False, observed=True).size()
```